# How can I set a transparent background colour in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to create an application that sits on the desktop, and the main graphic for the application is a png which I load into my program as a wxStaticBitmap.

My problem is that the png has parts which are transparent which wxStaticBitmap renders correctly. However, I need the transparency to show through to the desktop. As in, the window background is transparent and so are parts of the image and thus the desktop background is visible in the parts of the image which are transparent.

I have tried a couple of ideas, first I tried setting the background colour of my window to transparent, which didn't work for reasons unbeknownst to me(Although my best guess is that Windows doesn't support it), and I tried making the window itself transparent, which also turns my image transparent.

Other sites suggest creating custom widgets and other magical trickery, although I would prefer it if I could do it in pure wx.

My main code looks like this at the moment:

```
bool my_app::OnInit()
{
    my_frame* frame;
    wxStaticBitmap* background;

    wxImage::AddHandler(new wxPNGHandler());

    frame = new my_frame(wxT("my_window"));
    //bg is declared in the class declaration
    bg = wxBitmap(wxBufferedInputStream(wxFileInputStream(wxT(BACKGROUND_IMAGE)), 1000));

    background = new wxStaticBitmap(frame, frame->GetId(), bg, wxPoint(0, 0), wxSize(750, 300), 0L, "background");
    //my attempt at the elusive transparent background
    frame->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00));

    background->Show(true);
    frame->Show(true);

    return true;
}
```

Has anyone got any ideas?